# How do you retrieve a file from a repository using the github_api gem?

Tags: ruby, git, api, github

Most of the documentation is on authorization, and how to retrieve the basic objects the api provides.

What if I want a particular file from the repo?

Like, say me/repo/blob/master/readme.md

I've tried this:

```
g.git_data.blobs.get("me", "repo", "master/readme.md")
```

but I get a 404 error.

I'm working with a private repo, and created the object "g" with basic auth (username and password)

this is the gem i'm using: https://github.com/peter-murach/github/

Update, this is how I authed:

```
g = Github.new :basic_auth => "me:password"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it doesn't work for a private repository but to retrieve a file information from a public repository, the code is

```
g.repos.contents.get 'kulbirsaini', 'gitlist', 'web/Makefile'

g.repos.contents.get 'kulbirsaini', 'gitlist', 'README.md'
```

It must be something related to private repository. It'd be best to contact Github support.

**Summary of how to get a file  from a private repository:**

```
g = Github.new(:basic_auth => "username:password")
file = g.repos.contents.get("username", "private_repo_name", "repo_path_to_file_relative_to_branch")
human_readable_data = Base64.decode64(file)
```

example of `repo_path_to_file_relative_to_branch`:

```
/lib/core.rb
```

and NOT

```
/master/lib/core.rb
```

Comment: So, I got this to work with a public repository, but the content of the file is in base64 or something. How do I make it more human friendly?

Comment: Can you give `Base64.decode64` a try? You'll need to require 'base64' rubygem first.

Comment: that worked. cool. =D 

and this method actually works with private repos. i guess the secret was just .repos.contents.get

Comment: Great :) Can you update my answer with exact code so that others can benefit?

Comment: it's not terribly diffenetn =p